# Collecting AAD App Registration Permissions

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory

I’ve been asked by a customer to find a way to collect all permissions for all app registrations in the customer’s AzureAD tenant. The customer has 1500+ App Registrations, so checking each manually isn’t an option. Most of these are redundant but the customer wants to review all of them to look for Graph API permissions that they’ve deemed sensitive. The problem is, there isn’t a way to export this info in the portal and Get-AzADApplication doesn’t give me actual permissions, just friendly descriptions of them. The customer would like the ACTUAL Graph API, such as Mail.Read.

I’ve attempted to script this with the assistance of a few more senior PFEs, but we’ve been unable to make any progress passing various properties between Get-AzAdApplication, Get-AzADServicePrincipal and Get-AzureADOAuth2PermissionGrant. We reached the point where we were able to get the Graph API permissions from the Service Principals, but the resultant permissions were in an unusable format.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get this information into a concise format with (preferably) the Graph API permissions as mentioned above, I’d greatly appreciate it. I’d rather not go back to the customer and say it isn’t possible, as this is a new customer and I’d rather not say ‘No’ to my first task.

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into the answers? If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Cloud App Security for that purpose. This is tool designed, beside other features, especially for that purpose.

You open https://security.microsoft.com/ as a Global or Security Administrator, then you have quick overview on central place:
[image]

This will bring you to the MCAS portal, where you have solicit view on all applications with a rating, according to Microsoft standards for "Highly priviledged" access:
[image]

A direct view to applications, which users are using these applications, what permissions are granted. It even has filtering capabilities allowing you filter apps based on access level sevirity or even some Graph permissions - like Access e-mail on behalf of the user.

Your customer should really be using the Microsoft Security Center and monitor their security score: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/mtp/overview-security-center

Then looking at MCAS: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise-mobility-security/cloud-app-security

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/psignoret/41793f8c6211d2df5051d77ca3728c09) to list all delegated permissions and application permissions in Azure AD.

The key of the script is `Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId`.

Based on my test, the permissions in the result is in this format: `email offline_access openid profile User.Read`.

I think it's what you need.